# ServiceStack Razor page not rendered as HTML when visited in IE 8

Tags: razor, servicestack

I have a SS service returning json and html when coupled with a razor template. This template renders perfectly fine in Chrome and FF However, IE 8 only renders the json file, never the HTML. In IE 9 I can see in the F12 Dev Tools that the response header is returning application/json rather than text/html. This is being hosted in IIS 8.0. Does anyone have any suggestions what might be causing this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: It has to be the HTTP Request `Accept:` header. Can you post the full HTTP Request and HTTP Response headers (you can omit the Body) for IE8. If they're not visible in Dev tools you can use Fiddler.

Comment: @mythz I figured it out. I had the default content type on the endpoint config set to JSON. Once removed, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a simple fix. On the EndPointConfig I had set DefaultContentType = ContentType.Json. Once I removed that property IE was happy again.